# Test for statistical difference in proportions using R

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I am trying to solve the following problem:

A person can be classified as either GroupA, GroupB or GroupC.

I want to know how attribute1 (or attribute2) affects the proportion of observations in these groups.  Note that attribute1:attribute2 has a 1:N relationship.  Attribute1 has five possible values, A,B,C,D,E whilst attribute2 has two possible values: A,B.

Simulated data:

```
obsGroupA <- round(runif(40, 240, 63535))
obsGroupB <- round(runif(40, 2478, 95063))
obsGroupC <- round(runif(40, 3102, 104799))
propGroupA <- obsGroupA/(obsGroupA + obsGroupB + obsGroupC)
propGroupB <- obsGroupB/(obsGroupA + obsGroupB + obsGroupC)
propGroupC <- obsGroupC/(obsGroupA + obsGroupB + obsGroupC)
#propGroupA + propGroupB + propGroupC
attributeA <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")[runif(40, 1, 5)]
attributeB <- ifelse(attributeA %in% c("A", "B", "E"), "A", "B")
```

Model attempt:

```
#y <- cbind(obsGroupA, obsGroupB, obsGroupC)
y <- cbind(propGroupA, propGroupB, propGroupC)
model <- glm(y ~ attributeA)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in x[good, , drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too
>   long

Any ideas how I can perform a statistical test in R?
Any references to the correct statistical test would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have two problems: i) you don't know what you are doing from a statistical point of view, and ii) you don't know how to get R to do what you want. You will get help with i) on [stats.se] but not neccessarily ii) and you'll need to focus the question more on the what statistical approach should I use side of this question for this to be on-topic on [stats.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming in the first instance. OP needs statistical help and that will determine what needs to be done in software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should first look a bit into regression analysis like has been commented. You have some issues in understanding there. But, this is what you want:

```
obsGroupA <- round(runif(40, 240, 63535))
obsGroupB <- round(runif(40, 2478, 95063))
obsGroupC <- round(runif(40, 3102, 104799))
propGroupA <- obsGroupA/(obsGroupA + obsGroupB + obsGroupC)
propGroupB <- obsGroupB/(obsGroupA + obsGroupB + obsGroupC)
propGroupC <- obsGroupC/(obsGroupA + obsGroupB + obsGroupC)
#propGroupA + propGroupB + propGroupC
attributeA <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")[runif(40, 1, 5)]
attributeB <- ifelse(attributeA %in% c("A", "B", "E"), "A", "B")

y <- data.frame(propGroupA, propGroupB, propGroupC,attributeA,attributeB)
model <- glm(propGroupA ~ attributeA ,data=y )
summary(model)
```

Comment: Thanks - that will do for now.  I wasn't sure if there was something like a chi-squared contingency test.  I suppose as @Gavin Simpson suggests, this was more of a statistical problem.  I think the error I got above, was because I had 3 variables in the y <- cbind() statement.  I can change this to y <- cbind(propGroupA, 1-propGroupA).  As these are proportions, I believe the Statistics: An introduction using R, by Michael J. Crawely book suggests using family=binomial in the glm() statement.

Comment: It isn't a binomial though... a binomial is a 0/1 variable. In this case you have a continuous variable as your 'y' so you don't want to change to "family = binomial".

And you don't need a chi-squared. 

And you don't need to change y to what you suggested. Trust me. I have a PhD in economics and spent too much time on regression analysis. If you want to find the effect of the proportion of A of Attributes A & B, its PropA = AttA + AttB. If you want prop B it's PropB = AttA + AttB